# How to change gnome session locale?

Tags: gnome, locale, gdm

How do I change the default locale for my gnome session? I created `/etc/default/locale-local` with this content:

```
LANG=pt_PT.UTf-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
```

and added this to `/etc/pam.d/gdm3`, `/etc/pam.d/gdm3-autologin`, `/etc/pam.d/gdm-welcome`, `/etc/pam.d/login`, `/etc/pam.d/su` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session required pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale-local
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are doing it piecewise. The normal route is:

1. to check current settings:

   locale
2. check existing locales

   locale -a
3. chnage settings by either editing /etc/default/locale, or by using update-locale

   update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
4. generate locales

   locale-gen
   locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8
5. change gdm settings, by editing /var/cache/gdm/$USER/dmrc
6. rebooting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Debian documentation advices against changing form us_US.UTF-8 for maximum compatibility! Maybe there are better ways?...

Comment: us_US.UTF-8 does not exist. As for the locales I used, I wrote them as examples. I do not know what you want to set, you can set whatever you like. The info I gave you come from https://wiki.debian.org/Locale and from http://serverfault.com/questions/54591/how-to-install-change-locale-on-debian

Comment: Right. I meant en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: From the debian documentation I mentioned: "It is good idea to install system wide default locale as "en_US.UTF-8" for maximum compatibility." I was trying to do just that, while at the same time changing locales via the PAM modules.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just creating a ~/.xsessionrc file with locale configuration on it:

```
LANG=pt_PT.UTf-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
```

I don't think ~/.dmrc would work since my home is 700.